# What's the term for winning an argument using the elegance of manipulation?

Tags: political-philosophy, terminology, argumentation

Arguments can be won by utilizing a mixture of [ethos, pathos, and logos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modes_of_persuasion). Logos may either appeal using real logic (facts), or using deceptive logic (non-facts).

What's  the  **term** for  deceiving  people using a combination of pathos and  [non-factual logos](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/743269/13733), giving an appearance of solidity to pure wind and making [murders respectable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doublespeak#Main_contributors_to_Doublespeak)?

What's the **term** for gaining the upper hand by elegantly deceptive manipulations of words and emotions instead of by actual facts and real logic?

Comment: bad rhetoric i dunno

have you used a faulty premise, that logos is only fact based? i'm not sure everyone would agree with that anyway, fact is a strong word we may want to reserve for what is objective or verifiable in some particular way

Comment: Plato called people who use rethoric / philosophy to persuade people **sophists**.

Comment: I was about to try to suggest an edit here to try to frame it in somewhat more clear language -- something like "Is there a term for winning an argument by appealing to the hearer's emotions?" --But at any rate: could you try to specify what exactly is the problem that you are encountering in your study of philosophy? What precisely is it that you would like someone here to explain to you?

Comment: @JosephWeissman, I'm learning terminologies. Looking for a term. For example, appealing to the audience’s emotions would be called "pathos", appealing to authority would be called "ethos", appealing to simulation of logic would be called "logos". What's the term for deceiving people using a combination of pathos and non-factual logos, giving an appearance of solidity to pure wind and making murders respectable?

Comment: @YannikAmmann has it.  The word is 'sophistry': the triumph of rhetoric over logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been [pointed out in the comments](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/19722/whats-the-term-for-winning-an-argument-using-the-elegance-of-manipulation?noredirect=1#comment45286_19722), the closest correct answer to this question that I'm aware of is "sophistry".

That is, there is no term to my knowledge that is specifically about *winning* an argument using elegant/deceptive manipulation, but the act itself is known as **sophistry**. The people who do this are known as **[sophists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophist)**.

Being called a sophist wasn't always meant in a negative way, and indeed the original terms referred to people who were simply well-spoken. The word actually comes from Greek σόφισμα, *sophisma*, from σοφίζω, sophizo "I am wise"<sup>[[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophism)</sup>, but this changed over time.

> Owing largely to the influence of Plato and Aristotle, philosophy came
>   to be regarded as distinct from sophistry, the latter being regarded
>   as specious and rhetorical, a practical discipline. Thus, by the time
>   of the Roman Empire, a sophist was simply a teacher of rhetoric and a
>   popular public speaker.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophism